# C# Search in html, get links, follow them and grab some info from each page

Tags: c#, html, excel

I do NOT ask for the complete solution. It would be nice to hear any advice.

I'm sorry if that kind of question has already been asked.
Well, I have an html file containing a lot of lines (saved on my PC).
Example:

```
</li><li class="vertical" style="width: 20%;">
<div class="item-box vertical flex-auto">
<div class="image-box vertical center flex-auto"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.aliexpress.com/item/-/32794448855.html?scm=1007.14110.78103.0&amp;pvid=98337ce3-4886-4639-99f3-5dcaf226a0af" class="fade-in"><img src="./Электроника – Распродажа «Нам 7 лет» – AliExpress.com_files/HTB1fDZgPFXXXXXiapXXq6xXFXXXQ.jpg_350x350.jpg" alt="KingDian Новый Универсальный 2.5 &quot;до 3.5&quot; SSD HDD Окружающей Среды Пластмасс Адаптер Кронштейн Держатель Жесткого Диска для Настольных ПК"> </a></div>
```

This code contains links like that:

```
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/-/32794448855.html?scm=1007.14110.78103.0&amp;pvid=98337ce3-4886-4639-99f3-5dcaf226a0af
```

I need to grab all the links of the kind. Export them to any type of a document. Follow them. And on each page I need to find the line containing the price (Id "j-sku-discount-price" on every page).

```
<span id="j-sku-discount-price" class="p-price" itemprop="price" style="color: rgb(247, 43, 76);">4&nbsp;467,04</span>
```

This is the price found in html code:

```
4&nbsp;467,04
```

And export price so it would be close to its link.

E.g.:

```
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/-/32794448855.html?scm=1007.14110.78103.0&amp;pvid=98337ce3-4886-4639-99f3-5dcaf226a0af 4&nbsp;467,04
```

It would be perfect if it could be stored in Excel.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: It seems you are just giving us the requirements. Have you tried implementing this at all?

Comment: I did try. I have succeeded getting the price using Perl. But I don't underdstand how to do this using C#.I don't ask for a full solution. I would be glad to get any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use HtmlAgilityPack, and then use this on your HTML document.
But first download the string from site. Here you go, I helped you with your example:

```
string urlAddress = "https://www.aliexpress.com/item/-/32794448855.html?scm=1007.14110.78103.0&amp;pvid=98337ce3-4886-4639-99f3-5dcaf226a0af";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string data = "";
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
     Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
     StreamReader readStream = null;

     if (response.CharacterSet == null)
     {
         readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
     }
     else
     {
         readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
     }

     data = readStream.ReadToEnd();


     response.Close();
     readStream.Close();
}

HtmlDocument document2 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document2.LoadHtml(data);


var value = document2.GetElementbyId("j-sku-discount-price").InnerHtml; //value is "3.94"
```